# Convert function to class in javascript - problem with 'this' and private function

Tags: javascript, class, this

I'm trying to turn a function into a classe into a javascript.
The original function looks like this:

```
window.exampleClasses = (function(window, document, undefined) {
'use strict'; 
 var lang = 'en';
var user = null;
var isCheck = false;
var isAuthor = false;
var closed = true;

var session = {};
var data = {};

var timeout = null;

 function session(date, active) {
  session = {
     // some code here
  };


};

 function data() {
  session = {
     //some code here 
  };
  data = {};
    someObjects.firstFunction()
 };

  function timeoutFnc() {
 isCheck = false;
  isAuthor = false;
  someObjects.secondFunction();
 }

  // more functions 

var someObjects = {};

someObjects.firstFunction = function(params) {
  user.authKey = params;
}
 someObjects.secondFunction(){
 closed = !closed; 
 } 

 // more someObjects functions

 return {
 someObjects: function(c) {
        //some code 
        return someObjects;
    }
}
```

My class looks like this:

```
class exampleClasses {
   constructor() {
    this.lang = 'en';
    this.user = null;
    this.isCheck = false;
    this.isAuthor = false;
    this.closed = true;
    this.session = {};
    this.data = {};
    this.someObjects = {};
    this.someObjects.firstFunction = function(authKey){ window.a.config = authKey}; 
    this.someObjects.secondFuntion = function(){window.a.close = !window.a.close};
    this.someObjects.thridFunction = function(){}

    }

   session(date, active) {
    this.session = {
       // some code here
    };
};
    data() {
   this.session = {
       //some code here
    };
    this.data = {};
  this.someObjects.firstFunction()

};
}
```

Of course, there are more features for someObjects - so if we put them in the constructor - won't it hurt the performance? Do these features have to be in the constructor at all?

And now questions:

1) What is the better way to assign functions to this.someObjects? I can't make a separate class out of it.

2) "This" issue  -How do I refer to, for example, "this.close" with exampleClasses? 
Currently I'm doing it through window.a.someValue (I don't understand why this class is not under widnow.exampleClasses only under a) - but it's an ugly solution and it certainly exists simply.

3) how to save this last part of return from function in class?  Write it down as an additional function and if we need it we call it simply in a way:

```
var a = new exampleClasses()
 a.FunctionReturn
```

or another way?

I need some advices - I'm stuck and I don't have any idea to improve this code or  I don't know it is a good code (it's so very optymistic version - I don't belive that this code doesn't needs improves).

Comment: Remove equal sign from `class exampleClasses ={`.

Comment: You should really read the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: @Liam-ReinstateMonica I read documentation but still I don't have any idea how do this.